# Babeljs Standalone version not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, babeljs

I am trying to use Babeljs's stand alone version. It is working fine in Chrome, as expected, but not in IE where I need it to to work. NOTE: I only get this error on the latest version of BabelJS (Babel@6 reports no error) but I need it to work on the latest version (7 or older) in order to load the js file from a src instead of in the html.

My index.html looks like the following:

```
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CString.prototype.trimEnd"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

The error I get in IE is 'Symbol' is undefined in the babel.min.js file. Is this a bug on their part or is there something I can change on my end?

**EDIT**

if I use codebeautify.org/jsviewer to beautify the babel.min.js it looks like its referencing line 2633 which is: zi = Symbol.for("var used to be block scoped"),

I tried to add a reference to browser-polyfill.min.js. That threw a new error that said "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support this action" with a complicated stack trace that I don't understand.

**Edit 2**
After referencing polyfill for ES2015 and the TrimEnd method (first script) I still get the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'trimRight'" in the babel.min.js file.

Comment: To what symbol is the error referring?

Comment: For testing purposes, try to add a reference to `browser-polyfill.min.js` above the `babel.min.js`. See whether it helps to fix the error.

Comment: @isherwood if I use https://codebeautify.org/jsviewer to beautify the babel.min.js it looks like its referencing line 2633 which is: zi = Symbol.for("var used to be block scoped"),

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT it threw a different error when I added the reference to "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/polyfill@7.12.1/dist/polyfill.min.js". The new error is now "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support this action" with a complicated stack trace that I don't understand.

Comment: Put new information in your question, please. Not down here.

Comment: @JuliusSuddsSAC, it looks like you had added the `browser-polyfill.min.js` version 7.12.1. On my side, I have added version 5.6.15. It is not giving any error. I suggest you try to make a test with the 5.6 version and see whether if fix the error.